# Nagios monitoring for Exchange highavailability [Failover]

Tags: exchange-server, nagios, high-availability

What if we want to monitor the logs for Exchange highavailability for ID 306. I created the script but it gives the output with OK status without any event count where as there are several events are generated on the server due to automatic failover.

The script is:

```
./check_nrpe -t 30 -H IPAddress -p 5666 -c CheckEventLog -a file=Microsoft-Exchange-HighAvailability/Operational debug=true MaxWarn=1 MaxCrit=1 filter-generated=\<1d "filter=id = 306" truncate=1000 unique descriptions "syntax=%id%: (%count%)"
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: @o11c ... thanks for editing my text. but this was not i was expecting. I was expecting the solution.

Comment: This happens a lot when someone sees your post in one of the review queues but doesn't know anything about the subject.